# PHP - Bcrypt hash comparison always fails

Tags: php, hash, passwords, bcrypt

```
<?php

require 'password.php';
$hash1 = password_hash('testpassword',PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array('cost' => 11));
$hash2 = password_hash('testpassword',PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array('cost' => 11));

if(password_verify($hash1,$hash2)) echo 'Pass';
else echo 'Fail';

?>
```

I'm trying to use bcrypt provided by the password_compat library with PHP 5.4.16, but this script always outputs "Fail" even though it's comparing two hashes of the same password, why?

Edit - Just for clarification, I realize the hashes aren't identical, otherwise I'd just compare them instead of using a function.

Comment: This is the point of hashing. No two *are* alike. I find using Blowfish makes life easier too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass the password and the hash to `password_verify()`:

```
password_verify('testpassword', $hash1)
```

> Note: `testpassword` is password without hash

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

PS: `password_hash` generates different results expectedly, since it contains a random salt

Comment: Gah, can't believe I overlooked that, I saw that they used a variable in the example and I assumed it was another hash. Thanks a lot, I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: @Cains That's why I use a specific PHP IDE - It suggests me a function with its parameters, like this: "password_verify(password: string, hash: string) bool"